# wxPython StaticText Widget Font

Tags: python, wxpython

How do I set the font on a wxPython StaticText widget?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

use object.SetFont. For example (from wxpython in Action):

```
text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'my text', (20, 100))
font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
text.SetFont(font)
```

wx.Font has the following signature:

```
wx.Font(pointSize, family, style, weight, underline=False, faceName="", encoding=wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT)
```

family can be:

> wx.DECORATIVE, wx.DEFAULT,wx.MODERN,
>   wx.ROMAN, wx.SCRIPT or wx.SWISS.

style can be:

> wx.NORMAL, wx.SLANT or wx.ITALIC.

weight can be:

> wx.NORMAL, wx.LIGHT, or wx.BOLD

Comment: If anyone else is curious, the `SetFont` method comes from [the `Window` class](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html).

Comment: How can I set the font for only one section of the text? Would I have to use two different `StaticText` controls?

Comment: @fatuhoku A `wx.StaticText` can have multiple lines of text, but cannot handle multiple fonts. For multiple fonts or styles you could use, for example, an `wx.html.HTMLWindow`

Comment: Great, that's useful to know.