# How to format label in wxPython's StaticBox?

Tags: wxpython

I want to set the label (header?) of the `wx.StaticBox` widget in a 16pt bold font.

For a normal `wx.StaticText` I would do this (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201817/wxpython-statictext-widget-font)):

```
my_font = wx.Font(16, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label='My Text')
text.SetFont(my_font)
```

How is this done for the `wx.StaticBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by wx.StaticBox as far as I can tell. You will need to create a custom widget to accomplish this. I would recommend reading the following article:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls

The wxPython demo also has many examples of custom widgets. Check out anything in the "Custom Controls" or "Advanced Generic Widgets" sections for examples.