# Error while using set font in wx python in 2.7

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to change font setting in wx python in 2.7 version. I am getting error saying `SetFont is not defined`. Seems like 2.7 is not having `SetFont` command

```
import wx
text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'my text', (20, 100))
font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
text.SetFont(font)
```

Comment: Show how you are using the import statements.

Comment: I am using import wx

Comment: Maybe try `from wx import SetFont`...

Comment: Giving error saying ImportError: cannot import name SetFont

Comment: [See this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201817/wxpython-statictext-widget-font#comment27666035_5201842), I think that might be your answer.

Comment: I dodn't get ths. How can i use SetFont. Comment says SetFont is coming from Window class. How to use Window class

Comment: Post the rest of your code is what I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample will obviously not run. But the following minimal example will:

```
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frm = wx.Frame(None)
obj = wx.StaticText(frm, -1, 'fubar', (20, 100))
font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
obj.SetFont(font)    
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Tested on Win7(x64), Python 2.7.10 (32 bit), wxPython 3.0.2 (msw).

[image: Minimal wxPython Font sample]

Comment: Also works on wxPython_Phoenix 3.0.3dev-something (msw), 32 bit.